# app ready for appstore but not for test-flight distribution

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, testflight, entitlements, app-store-connect

we recently ran into an issue where after the build is uploaded into the appstore connect.

it's ready to be published for public but couldn't release it via test flight and here is the excerpt from rejection mail.

```
As discussed during the call, the reason pre-release version x.y.z build x.y.azxcv.dfg of your app is not available for testing is because the build was not signed with a valid App Store distribution provisioning profile. 

To distribute a beta app to testers, you need to re-sign the app with a Distribution Provisioning profile that contains the beta entitlement. Distribution Provisioning profiles can be generated in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles portal.
```

Little confused on what to do further because the provisioning profile indeed is valid. what are they talking about beta entitlement and it's little confusing.

the app already as all the entitlement(capabilities turned on in provisioning profile) for it function and app has been functionaly tested to be working but with testflight distribution I'm facing the issue

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: How are you signing the build?  Are you using automatic signing with Xcode?

Comment: manual signing @Paulw11

Comment: Try using automatic signing, otherwise provide details of your signing steps; it seems you have something wrong. Are you using Xcode 11?

Comment: @Paulw11 noo , we're using scripts to change bundle identifier ,provisioning profile and certificate of already signed ipa and pushing it to app-store connect

Comment: Then you need to examine that process. It isn’t doing something correctly.

Comment: There is no such thing called beta entitlement... we have to add or something